# Changing the order of address fields

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I am trying to order the address fields so that they read

- Business name
- First name
- Last name
- Company name
- Address 1
- Address 2
- City
- State
- Zip
- Phone

I moved some of the items around in the `addressFields` array but I can't seem to move the Country or the State. Is there a way to do this?

```
      {% set countries = craft.commerce.countriesList %}
      {% set states = craft.commerce.statesArray %}
      {% set addressFields = [
          { key: 'businessName', label: 'Business Name', required: false },
          { key: 'firstName', label: 'First Name', required: true },
          { key: 'lastName', label: 'Last Name', required: true },
          { key: 'address1', label: 'Address 1', required: false },
          { key: 'address2', label: 'Address 2', required: false },
          { key: 'city', label: 'City', required: false },
          { key: 'zipCode', label: 'Zip Code', required: false },
          { key: 'phone', label: 'Phone', required: false },
      ] %}


      {% set modelName = modelName is defined ? modelName : 'address' %}
      {% set model = address is defined ? address : null %}

      <div class="addressBox {{ modelName }}">
          {% for field in addressFields %}
              <div class="form-group {% if model and model.getErrors(field.key) %}has-error{% endif %}">
                  <label for="{{ modelName }}-{{ field.key }}">{{ field.label }}{{ field.required ? '*' : '' }}</label><br/>
                  <input type="text" id="{{ modelName }}-{{ field.key }}" class="u-full-width" name="{{ modelName }}[{{ field.key }}]"
                         value="{{ model ? model[field.key] : '' }}">      
                  {% if model and model.getErrors(field.key) %}
                      <span class="flash">{{ model.getErrors(field.key)|join }}</span>
                  {% endif %}
              </div>
          {% endfor %}

              <div class="form-group {% if model and model.getErrors('stateId') %}has-error{% endif %}">
              <label for="{{ modelName }}-stateId">State</label><br/>
              <select class="address-state" name="{{ modelName ~ '[stateId]' }}">
                  {% set options = (model and states[model.countryId] is defined ? states[model.countryId] : []) %}
                  {% for key, option in options %}
                      {% set optionValue = (model ? model.stateId : '') %}
                      <option value="{{ key }}" {% if key == optionValue %} selected{% endif %}>{{ option }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
              </select>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group {% if model and model.getErrors('countryId') %}has-error{% endif %}">
              <label for="{{ modelName }}-countryId">Country</label><br/>
              <select class="address-country" name="{{ modelName ~ '[countryId]' }}">
                  {% for key, option in countries %}
                      {% set optionValue = (model ? model.countryId : '') %}
                      <option value="{{ key }}" {% if key == optionValue %} selected{% endif %}>{{ option }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
              </select>
              {% if model and model.getErrors('countryId') %}
                  <span class="flash">{{ model.getErrors('countryId')|join }}</span>
              {% endif %}
          </div>



      </div>

          {% includejs %}
          var states = {{ craft.commerce.statesArray|json_encode|raw }};

          $('select.address-country').change(function ()
          {
              var cid = $(this).val();
              var $states = $(this).closest('.addressBox').find('select.address-state');
              $states.find('option').remove();

              if (states.hasOwnProperty(cid))
              {
                  for (var id in states[cid])
                  {
                      var state = states[cid][id],
                              $option = $('<option/>');

                      $option.attr('value', id).text(state);
                      $states.append($option);
                  }
              }

          });

          $('select').addClass('form-control input-sm');

          {% endincludejs %}
```

Answer (score 2):

The State and Country fields are output outside your `addressFields` loop so will always appear after all of the fields in that loop.

On a recent project I just hard coded each field as it gave me greater control for things like input type, validation messages and layout.

If you wanted to continue using your `addressFields` array you could add a query to output your country/state select input.

```
{% if field.key == 'country' %}
  <select class="address-{{ field.key }}" name="{{ modelName }}[{{ field.key }}]">
    {% for key, option in countries %}
      {% set optionValue = (model ? model.countryId : '') %}
      <option value="{{ key }}" {% if key == optionValue %} selected{% endif %}>{{ option }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
{% endif %}
```